# batch file for encoding videos with ffmpeg - "variable": %%a

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg, encode

what is the meaning of '%%a' and '%%~na' in this expression: http://www.pasteall.org/58875?

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"pause
```

I want to batch encode a couple of video files. all are in the same folder with nothing else in it. I found explanations which tell that it is a variable. but for what does a variable like this stand?

working on win 7 ult 64bit.

Answer (score 3):

`%%~na` will return the file name without the path or extension of a file returned by a `for` loop.

From the output of `for /?`:

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
```

Comment: and what is the meaning of '%%a'?

Comment: @labrat - `%%a` is the variable that was selected to be used for that particular `for` loop. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php

Answer (score 1):

%%a is a special parameter , which will be substituted by the value of a FOR loop, the IN ( ....) clause is evaluated and %%a set to a different value in each iteration.

Comment: where can I find explanations understandable for a non-professional concerning 'in clause' and 'for loop'? further more I don't understand the syntax of the expression in my opening post.

Comment: each result of my researches is like " 'a' is used in order to set 'b' to 'c' and then return to 'd'. it doesn't help me at all, when I don't know what 'a' is, nor 'b', 'c' or 'd'...

Comment: OK,  let me explain the other way which you might like ;  for is used for looping through set of line in a file , or set of lines of a output of command in the section () , in your code you have used (*.*) which means your for loop will take all files in the directory where your batch file runs in a sequence line by line and pass the value to the variable %%a used in the for loop . later %%a can be used which has the values of for loop and convert it to video file.

Comment: thank you very much. meanwhile I managed to encode a sequence of videos with a batch file. see http://www.pasteall.org/58898.
but in general I really need to become accustomed to the whole topic.

questions:

are the quotation marks which are often found in example code lines required in my case (see pasted code)? I let the batch file run without the quotation marks and it seems to make no difference.

Comment: replacing the file extension '.mp4' in the argument list by an asterisk (http://www.pasteall.org/58899) leads to an error message:
  
'invalid data found when processing input'.

however this doesn't seem to effect the result. this error also appears when the work folder contains nothing else than the source video files, the output folder and the batch file.

what is the reason for this error/what does it mean?

Comment: can the variable used in the for loop be any small letter as long as the same letter is used in every place of the command?

Comment: you write: "%%a is a special parameter , which will be substituted by the value of a FOR loop, the IN ( ....) clause is evaluated and %%a set to a different value in each iteration."

what is this value? just a result of a computer operation?

Answer (score 0):

for %%a in ("*.mp4")do ffmpeg -y -i "%%a" -i"%%a" -filter_complex "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w"    -preset ultrafast  output"%%a".mp4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).